# I need help to display the id of a table but i'm having its memory address

Tags: jpa, jsf, el

I have 2 classes ordinateur and salle mapped by ManyToOne in ordinateur and i want to display to id of salles in ordinateur table but what I get is the memory address of salle

```
    This is the mapping in the ordinateur class
    @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="code_salle")
        private Salle salle;
        
        public Salle getSalle() {
            return salle;
        }
     and here where i want to display it 
    <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Code de la salle</f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{ordinateur.salle}"></h:outputText>
                </h:column>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your EL expressing is referring the `salle` property in `ordinateur`, so, as a result you will get the `Salle` object. EL will call the `toString()` on objects, and that's the output you are seeing. What you need to output is `#{ordinateur.salle.id}`.

And by the way, you are not seeing a memory address, but the class name and the object's hash code. See the default `toString()` implementation:

```java
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```